# What is ISAPI Rewrite, and can/should this be used with asp.net 4.0 instead of MS's ISS Rewrite?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis, isapi

I've been told by people that Microsoft's IIS Rewrite 2.0 for use on my II7 is okay, but that [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) "is way better and it's what good developers use".  As I went to the website, I noticed things about .htaccess and such, and it struck me as more of a thing for php websites, since I'm on a Windows server and .htaccess doesn't apply to me.

My company's website is Visual Studio / vb / asp.net 4.0 / windows server

Can I use this ISAPI Rewrite, and would you recommend it for making the most friendly URLs?  Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe both are really the same thing, IIS Rewrite module being written by Microsoft and **free**. Both will allow you to rewrite your URLs and it depends on you to come up with most friendly ones ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jakub.  I didn't realize that ISAPI came with a price.  It appears you can do a lot with it, though.  But I suppose you can do a lot with IIS rewrite as well.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond!